# Best way to add items to a log window from a Class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add a "log" message from my class to a `ListBox` on my form. Within the form I would just be able to use `lblog.add("message")`, but as I'm trying to clean up my code, what is the best way to pass the "message" to the front end?

I found a suggestion that has the code below, but wondering if there is a simpler way?

Form:

```
// This is all required so that we can call the function from another class 
public void publicLogMessage(string message)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new OutputDelegate(logMessage), message);
    }
}

public delegate void OutputDelegate(string message);

public void logMessage(string message)
{
    lblog.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + "  " + message);
}
```

Class:

```
//This is required so that we can call the "PublicLogMessage" function on the main form
public frmMain formToOutput;

public speechRecognition(frmMain f)
{
    formToOutput = f;
}
```

Usage:

```
formToOutput.logMessage
```

Comment: WPF or winforms?

Comment: Winforms sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You now have a pretty tight coupling between your algorithm and your ouput method. Your algorithm knows *all* about your output method (for example that it's a form with a specific signature).

I would suggest decoupling it:

```
private readonly Action<string> log;    

public speechRecognition(Action<string> log)
{
    this.log = log;
}

public void DoWork()
{
   this.log("work started");

   // ...

   this.log("work in progress");

   // ...

   this.log("work ended");
}
```

This class knows nothing about the logging method. It only knows it gets a string. The class controlling both the output method (form) and algorithm (class above) can then link them together:

```
var form = new YourFormWithLoggingWindow();

var algorithm = new speechRecognition(form.publicLogMessage);
```

Now the algorithm will log to the form. You could have called it using

```
var algorithm = new speechRecognition(Console.WriteLine);
```

and it would log to the console in a Console Application. The algorithm does not care and does not need your form to compile. It's independent. Your form does not know the algorithm either. It's independent, too.

You could even have unit testing that checks the logging:

```
var log = new List<string>();
var algorithm = new speechRecognition(log.Add);

algorithm.DoWork();

Assert.AreEqual(log.Count, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if/else` when using `InvokeRequired`, I don't think there are other optimizations at the moment.

```
public void publicLogMessage(string message)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(new OutputDelegate(logMessage), message);
    else 
        logMessage(message);
}

public delegate void OutputDelegate(string message);
private void logMessage(string message)
{
    lblog.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + "  " + message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void listboxlrm(byte[] text)
{
    if (this.listBox2.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(listboxlrm);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
    }
    else
    {
        byte[] convert = new byte[text[4]];
        Array.Copy(text, 6, convert, 0, text[4]);
        string yourtext = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(convert);
        this.listBox2.Items.Insert(0, string.Format(yourtext));
    }
}
```

I am using that method.... If you use insert always add the top.